# How do I use Google Translate API from a java program on a client?

Tags: java, google-api, translation

What I have done so far:

- I setup a project in google developer console
- I setup the billing
- I assigned the translation api. It is switched on . ON button is green

Now I get confused with the key setup. What type of key do I have to setup and which parameters do I have to provide to call the api from my java-programm ?

[image]

My tries so far resulted in the following error, when trying the get-request with a browser:

```
Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to go to your project in the Google Developers Console, then to **APIS & Auth**, click on Credentials and Create new Client ID. Choose the type of your application (if it is a Java application, it would be Installed Application > Other) and your key would be the Client secret.

You could also use a public key instead of OAuth. To do that instead of selecting Create new Client ID, try Create new Key, and then Browser key.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I added a screenshot for the key generation and I do not have your mentoined "installed Application" as choice. But I now succeeded with using the browser key and leaving the ip's empty. This worked from the browser and I hope it works from my java too. I try....

Comment: From your screenshot you are using a public key, not the one you set up the billing for, I believe. To use the key you are paying for you need to Create new Client ID as I explained, not Create new key, as your screenshot suggests.

Comment: It works with the Browser Key, because URLConnection acts as a browser it seems.

Comment: Yes it should but I'd recommend using the OAuth choice. Anyway, it seems like you solved your problem yourself :)

Comment: Thanks a lot and sorry. You could modify your answer with the solution and I will accept it for your efforts.

Comment: I edited it, in case someone needs the information in the future.